# Does differentiation symbol need parentheses or?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

Suppose I have this expression:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x})^2 + 6$$

Does it mean to differentiate $6$ too or just the first term?

---

This is an exercise on a calculus course that I'm doing on Coursera.
Unfortunately anything printed has a weight greater than the onlooker's intelligence. It's beyond me how people on the course forum including the two professors who happen to be doctors can't understand the basic and obvious meaning of parentheses.

[image]

Comment: I think $6$ is included. Otherwise the power would be for the whole $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ term

Comment: You should change one of your 6's to something else, now it's a bit confusing (look at the first comment for example)

Comment: $\large{\tt\mbox{Computer Programmer's Rule}}\  \mbox{applies: If in doubt use parentheses.}$

Comment: Felix, I don't think this is a matter of doubt. In its current form it only means that 6 is not to be differentiated and there's no doubt about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short of the possibility that you are reading someone else's bad writing,

$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)^2+6 = 2e^{2x}+6 \neq \frac{d}{dx}\left((e^x)^2+6\right) = 2e^{2x}.$$

Mathematical notation is supposed to be quite unambiguous, and so I would not differentiate the constant unless I knew that the author was just being sloppy and really intended the latter.

The differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ distributes over addition just like scalar multiplication, and so these parentheses are quite necessary if it is the author's intention to differentiate the 6.

Comment: Might add that this unambiguous notation part is usually called *order of operations* or *operator preference*. So I think one can say that the differential operator has the same preference as multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

What is probably meant is to differentiate $\text{e}^{2x}+6$ with respect to $x$.

What it really means written that way is to differentiate $e^x$ with respect, to $x$, square the answer and add $6$.

How it should have been written is
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left( e^{2x}+6\right)
$$